# PHP: calling a function with return-value within a class

Tags: php, function, class, return-value

When I do this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function func1()
    {
        $temp = $this->func2();
        return $temp;
    }
    function func2()
    {
        return "bla2";
    }
}
```

the website stays empty and it seems like PHP crashed due to an error (no entry in error.log, though)

But when I do this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function func1()
    {
        $temp = "bla1"; //$this->func2();
        return $temp;
    }
    function func2()
    {
        return "bla2";
    }
}
```

it works; "bla1" ist being returned. Obviously I am calling func2 in a wrong way. How is it correct?

Extending my original post with this excerpt from my php-script. I have actually stripped down the original code to this and tried it -> it still causes an error.
It may be important to mention that it is a plugin for wordpress. Without the function-call it does work and returns text which is being displayed by wordpress.

```
<?php
    add_shortcode("pd",array("pdCategories","ShortcodeParse_c"));
    $pd = new pdCategories();

    class pdCategories
    {
        public function ShortcodeParse_c($atts)
        {
            $temp = "";
            $temp.= "test<br>"; //this works
            $temp.= $atts["category"]; //this also works
            $temp.= $this->ShowCategories_c($atts["category"]); //this causes an error
            return $temp;
        }
        
        private function ShowCategories_c($kats)
        {
            $temp = "starting...<br>"; //init
            return $temp;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: $temp = $this->func2() -> missing ; here ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I forgot to type the semicolon (;) after that line. But only here in this post. It is present in the real code.

Comment: Then, the code is correct. Maybe the problem is somewhere else, how do you call this method?

Comment: Best is to not _type_ your code here, but _copy/paste_ it. There might be other typos in your original code that aren't visible here

Comment: I have extended my original post with the (stripped) original code.

Comment: I am guessing here: does $atts["category"] exist?

Comment: Yep: $temp.= $atts["category"]; returns whatever I put in that attribute, i.e. 162,114,81,186

Comment: Maybe I should take some sort of "class course" to learn how to use classes properly. I have never used classes because I (still) don't see an advantage, even though I have read many reports about classes and why they are useful. For decades I have written my programs and websites with "just" functions and they work perfectly fine. Even that Wordpress plugin this thread is about already works - but without using classes. But since everyone else is using classes, I thought, why not give it a try.

Comment: It may be the case that your function is called statically (`MyClass::func1()`), this would explain why the second scenario works and the first one doesn't (as the first one uses `$this` inside the method). Basically, you should find out how `ShortcodeParse_c()` is being called.

Comment: You can add: 

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

to see the error